# Why does AWS S3 GUI put { "_1": } around my JSON file?

Tags: json, amazon-s3

I have a valid JSON file which I am uploading to a bucket in AWS S3 directly by using the GUI.

```
[
    {
        "attribute1" : "foo1",
        "attribute2" : 123,
        "attribute3" : "bar1"
    },
    {
        "attribute1" : "foo2",
        "attribute2" : 123,
        "attribute3" : "bar2"
    }
]
```

When I use the AWS GUI Select from (preview) with settings File format = JSON, JSON type = JSON lines and Compression = None, I get the following output:

```
{
    "_1": [
        {
            "attribute1" : "foo1",
            "attribute2" : 123,
            "attribute3" : "bar1"
        },
        {
            "attribute1" : "foo2",
            "attribute2" : 123,
            "attribute3" : "bar2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you have an idea why S3 puts the { "_1": }, around my JSON file?

Comment: Might be relevant: [SelectObjectContent - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_SelectObjectContent.html) mentions "Assuming that you are not using column headers, you can identify columns using positional headers", and gives the example: `SELECT s._1, s._2 FROM S3Object s WHERE s._3 > 100`

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send it like below

`{
        "attribute1" : "foo1",
        "attribute2" : 123,
        "attribute3" : "bar1"
 }
 {
        "attribute1" : "foo2",
        "attribute2" : 123,
        "attribute3" : "bar2"
 }`

you can see this s3 json query

`[
   {
        "attribute1" : "foo1",
        "attribute2" : 123,
        "attribute3" : "bar1"
   },
   {
        "attribute1" : "foo2",
        "attribute2" : 123,
        "attribute3" : "bar2"
   }
]`

good~